# How could I create a copy of a gameobject hierachy which mimics all positions, movements, etc of the original? Like a hologram of the original?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am building a 3d Billiard game in VR using Unity3d.

I try to display a miniature copy of the billiard "table" (actually a cube), like it is at any given moment.

I tried instantiating the root of the billiard hierarchy, just to find out it will instantiate the original gameObject (runnings its Start() methods) which totally makes sense, just not what i am trying to do.

In practice I have a billiard root, which has all the geometry of the table, and all balls as children, those balls can interact physically. 
On button press I try to create a hologram of the table, with all its balls at their position at any given time.

So If a player hits a ball and it moves in the original, it should display the same in the miniature.

I thought it might be possible to translate the ball positions (and table rotation etc) every frame to the miniature. but that seams very un optimal.

```cs
var midPoint = (leftHand.transform.position + rightHand.transform.position) / 2;
var miniature = Instantiate(gameObject, midPoint, transform.rotation);
miniature.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
```

this obviously does not work as i described above. It creates a completely new instance of the billiard cube. (this code was run from a script inside the billiard root)

Comment: An easy way but that may not suit your need, is having a second camera that only render your billard to a render texture, and show that as part of an UI or something. I do something similar for a minimap

Comment: @Jichael I am kinda necroing this thread, but: this would not really work in VR, cause of stereo vision, 2D representation of a 3D object looks .. off..
But in would work fine in 2D!

Answer (score 1):

The board itself probably doesn't move, so you can just make holograms and simulate the balls.

Since Unity 2018.2, you can create physics scenes and simulate them manually.

For that problem you would need to:

1. Stop physics simulations.

   - [`Physics.autoSimulation = false;`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics-autoSimulation.html)
2. Create a new scene for independent physics simulation.

   - [`var physicsPreviewScene = SceneManager.CreateScene("Physics Preview Scene", sceneParams);`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.CreateScene.html)
3. Copy the physics-relevant objects and components to the preview scene.

   - Many ways to do it, but basically colliders, rigidbodies, and for objects you need visuals for, renderers.
   - You can use caching to avoid creating these every time.
   - You can also, in theory, have the simulation on the main scene, but then you need to make kinematic all the stuff you don't want simulated, and there are some gotchas.
4. Then simulate manually.

   - Get the [`PhysicsScene`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PhysicsScene.html) from the preview scene: `var physicsScene = physicsPreviewScene.GetPhysicsScene();`
   - Simulate: [`physicsScene.Simulate();`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PhysicsScene.Simulate.html)

---

So yea, short of avoiding the components unrelated to physics in the copies, you can't avoid the duplicates; only mitigate their impact with pooling and/or caching.

---

Another technique is to use casting (spherecasting, in this case) to make a mockup physics simulation, stepping multiple casts with `velocity`, `acceleration` (gravity for example) and `Time.fixedDeltaTime`, and reacting to intercepts/hits as collisions, with `Vector3.Reflect`or something similar. But this will only give you an approximation of how physics would react, and is not going to be an actual (accurate) physics simulation like having multiple PhysicsScenes will.